# Sketching a PDF function (discrete)

Tags: plotting, functions, probability-or-statistics, distributions, discrete

I have this distribution: $Probability = 2/(\operatorname{cosech⁡}(x))(k x^{2k}))/((2k))$ for $k$ = 1 to infinity.

How can I do a sketch for any value of $x$?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried, displayed in Mathematica format.

Comment: I think you meant $(k a^{2k})$ instead of $(k a^2 k)$

Comment: I reverted the edit you made yesterday as it was made without explanation, made the formula unintelligible, and invalidated the existing answer. If the existing answer does not solve your problem, you can explain why in a comment under the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define the distribution with [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

```
dist[a_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   2/(a*Sinh[a])*k*a^(2*k)/((2*k)!),
   {k, 1, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > 0}];

Manipulate[
 μ = Mean[dist[a]];
 σ = StandardDeviation[dist[a]];
 ub = Ceiling[μ + 8*σ]; (* upper bound for plot *)
 Column[{
   StringForm["μ = ``, σ = ``",
    NumberForm[μ // N, {5, 3}],
    NumberForm[σ // N, {5, 3}]],
   DiscretePlot[Evaluate@
     PDF[dist[a], x], {x, 1, ub},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotStyle -> Darker[Red],
    FillingStyle ->
     Directive[Opacity[1, Darker[Red]], Thick],
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"k", 
        "Pr[X\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]k]"}),
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{a, 5}, 0.25, 10, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For revised distribution

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(2/5)*k*x^(5*k)/(2*k)

(* x^(5 k)/5 *)

(totalProb = Sum[x^(5 k)/5, {k, 1, Infinity}, 
   GenerateConditions -> True]) // InputForm

(* ConditionalExpression[-1/5*x^5/(-1 + x^5), 
 Abs[x] < 1 && x^5 != 1] *)
```

The total probability is not equal to one so the probabilities must be normalized.

```
Assuming[0 < x < 1,
 Sum[(-1 + 1/x^5)*x^(5*k), {k, 1, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)

dist[x_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   (-1 + 1/x^5)*x^(5*k), {k, 1, Infinity, 1},
   Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}];

μ[x_] = Mean[dist[x]]

(* 1/(1 - x^5) *)

σ[x_] = StandardDeviation[dist[x]]

(* Sqrt[x^5/(-1 + x^5)^2] *)
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{StringForm["μ = ``, σ = ``", 
    NumberForm[μ[x] // N, {5, 3}], NumberForm[σ[x] // N, {5, 3}]],
   DiscretePlot[PDF[dist[x], k],
    {k, 1, Ceiling@Max[5, μ[x] + 3 σ[x]]},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotStyle -> Darker[Red],
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Darker[Red]], Thick],
    FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
       {"k", 
        "Pr[X\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]k]"}),
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{x, 0.95}, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]